Linkedln проблемы с регистрацией noCaptch
пытаюсь зарегиться уже много дней не дней. всё зависает на этапе проверки робот я или человек, ошибка: Ответный пользовательский код noCAPTCHA отсутствует или недействителен. кто-нибудь сталкивался?
работаю на ubuntu 22.04

Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не соответствует тематике ресурса

У меня тоже была такая проблема. Попробуй с телефона. У меня получилось. После ввода имени и фамилии капча не появляется.
ОС: Android.
Браузер: Chrome.
